# antlr4 and international characters

Tags: unicode, antlr4

I have been using antlr4 to parse a German document and so far I have done the following to parse the text that includes German characters:

```
LETTERS:
[a-zA-Z_\u00DC\u00FC\u00D6\u00F6\u00C4\u00E4\u00DF]; // hex unicodes for ÜüÖöÄäß
```

what is the best way to describe lingual characters of all languages in Unicode in a way that antlr understands, without specifying each language/character individually? say, the french, Arabic, or Chinese, Japanese characters?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use character ranges corresponding to the desired Unicode classes.  Even then, the result can be a bit clumsy. See this [worked example](https://github.com/GRosenberg/grammars-v4/blob/master/antlr4/LexUnicode.g4).

The raw data available in the Unicode standard's Appendix tables can be stripped and munged into a usable format with just a bit too much effort. ;)